# configuring pam with flat files backend

Tags: authentication, pam

I would like to configure pam module to use flat files for authentication. Basically I need same thing like `pam_unix` just with possibility to use different files (other than `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`).

Is there existing pam module that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

pam_pwdfile is probably what you want.